# Problem with Apache Commons Id UUID Version 1 generation

Tags: java, classpath, jetty, apache-commons, uuid

My problem is to generate version 1 UUIDs. We use Jetty 6.x, Maven (to start Jetty among other things) and [Apache Commons ID](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/id/) (to generate UUID version 1 from the current time).

[Apache Commons ID](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/id/) requires a configuration file that is told to the JVM, using a parameter, e.g. 'org.apache.commons.id.uuid.config.resource.filename=commons-id-uuid.xml'. I checked the [Apache Commons ID](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/id/) code and it tries to find the file from the classpath. Jetty's [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading) states that WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes are in the classpath. The 'commons-id-uuid.xml' can be found from the deployed war file from the root of WEB-INF/classes directory but Jetty cannot load it:

```
Message: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: commons-id-uuid.xml loaded as system resource is null
```

Jetty was started using the following command:

```
mvn jetty:run -Dorg.apache.commons.id.uuid.config.resource.filename=commons-id-uuid.xml
```

Any idea what is going wrong? We just need to generate UUID version 1 identifiers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you not use the JDK UUID (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) ?

Comment: We just need to generate UUID from the current time easily. The JDK UUID class' constructor takes most significant bits and least significant bits. That is rather low level. Also, there is randomUUID (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29), which returns type 4 UUID and we need type 1 UUID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least 2 better UUID generation libraries than apache commons one:

- [Java Uuid Generator](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator) (JUG)
- [UUID 3.1](http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/)

which do not require xml config files. Maybe consider one of them instead?

Comment: Thanks for the information! Actually we didn't resolve the problem, since we changed the database to another one. However, this is something we need to resolve this particular problem in the future. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: FYI: JUG is now located at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome and makes use of modern JDK6 features (quite in contrast to the outdated implementation hosted at the above URL)